# how to use wso2 esb with cxf?

Tags: cxf, wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to deploy CXF Web Services in wso2 ESB ?

Currently I have started referring documentation of wso2 from [WSO2 User Guide](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/User+Guide) and I want to deploy an existing CXF Web Service to ESB. So any information on this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CXF Web Services hosting is provided through [WSO2 Application Server](http://wso2.com/products/application-server/). You can install Application Server feature in ESB to get that functionality in ESB. Follow [this guide](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Installing+Features) to install features. Refer [this AS doc](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AS510/JAX-WS+and+JAX-RS+Support) for information on CXF support in WSO2 AS.